# Windows DDK development with MinGW?

Tags: c++, mingw, wdk

Is it possible to develop a Windows driver (specifically a PDF-like printer driver that displays the data on-screen instead of actually printing) without using Visual Studio?  I'm thinking of using free C++ tools such as MinGW/gcc.

Comment: Everything you need, compiler, linker and debugger, is included with the DDK.  Free.

Comment: @Hans Passant: minus the IDE!

Comment: @snmc - An IDE is pretty useless for driver development, doesn't help you build nor debug.  It's an editor, that's all.  You can get that for free as well, the Express edition is a decent editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both the Windows SDK and the Windows DDK come with the Visual C++ compiler. You don't need Visual Studio for this, though you may have some success with the free Express editions. I'd prefer this over MinGW anytime.

Comment: Op was asking for _free_ c++ tools. While it depends on Rob's definition of free, mingw has a far more open license, and it can be of relevance for professional driver development; see here: http://groveronline.com/2008/07/mingw-cross-compilation-adventure/. Also, if one prefers to actually understand the linking and how the compiler is handling things, mingw/g++ with Make is going to be much better.

Answer (score 1):

Your bigger problem is going to be displaying the data on-screen from a driver.  Drivers run in the context of the spooler, which is a service and therefore can't display a UI.  You're going to need a non-driver app running in the user's session to display the data.  You could use pipes or even files to pass the data from the driver to the display app.